# Obligation to pray in minyan in less than 1km (distance) or 18 min (time)

Tags: tefilla, minyan

A Jew who lives less than 1 kilometer (walking) or less than 18 minutes (driving) from a minyan is obligated to pray in that minyan. What do these halachos look like if the Jew needs to travel more than 1 kilometer to catch a ride that takes less than 18 minutes to reach the nearest minyan? And what do these halachos look like if the route to the minyan closest to the minyan is by metro, given that the metro trip itself takes less than 18 minutes, but you have to walk more than 1 kilometer (after disembarking) to get to the minyan? Does traffic count in those 18 minutes by car? This question is for an urban area.

Comment: If total (door to door) travel time is more than 18 minutes then I’m pretty sure he is exempt.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question — the time one is obligated to invest in fulfilling the mitzvah is a total of 18 minutes according to the Avnei Yashfeh 6:5. Therefore if one can reach the minyan in 18 minutes, there would still be an obligation to pray with that minyan. Others learn that it is referring to actual distance (See Shevet HaLevi 8:19).

The amount that one has to travel is the amount of time it takes to travel 4 milin — which is 72 minutes of travel time in front of him [in the direction one is traveling in], and 18 minutes (1 mil) to the sides or back [of the direction of travel]. This is calculated by time; and not dependent on the mode of travel.

Sources:
See Biur Halachah [163:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.163.1.2); Mishnah Berurah [92:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.92.17); Az Nidberu [6:66](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=880&st=&pgnum=107); Ishei Yisrael, chap. 8, footnote 70.

Mishnah Berurah [90:52](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.90.52) explains that if one is sitting at home is considered as one who has to travel backwards. He also warns against those who are at home and are lazy to go pray the noon and evening prayers.

Even though many learn that the 18 minutes time is measured from one's current location; the Kaf HaChaim [90:107](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.90.107.1) considers it like the tekhoum shabbat i.e. the time (distance) of 18 minutes only starts from outside the city.

My own addendum: I'm assuming the time one has to travel was only placed due to travel being difficult historically; nowadays, being that it's easier to travel,  one should probably make an effort to go even further than 18 minutes out of the way.